# Redirecting after successful Login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authentication

My **User** wants to **Sign up** for an **Event**. The first layout is for registering for that Event. But my **User** already has an account and chooses an option which automatically leads him to **login** route. After he has been succesfully **authentificated** I want to redirect him to my **payment** form. Normally my succesful authetification would return my Users **profile**. I want to keep that flow **unless** the User is registering for this Event. My project is Laravel **4.2**. Can I use **tokens** or something else? Any options?

This is the **AuthRepository** function:

```
class AuthRepository implements AuthRepositoryInterface {

    private $messageBag;
    private $errors;

    public function __construct(MessageBag $messageBag) {
        $this->messageBag = $messageBag;
    }

public function postLogin() {

        $remember_me = (Input::get('remember_me') == 1 ? true : false);

        try
        {
            // Login credentials
            $credentials = array(
                'email'    => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password'),
            );

            // Authenticate the user
            $user = \Sentry::authenticate($credentials, $remember_me);

            // Redirect to homepage
            return Redirect::route('profile')->with('success' , trans('users::success.login_success'));

        }
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e)
        {
            //echo 'Login field is required.';
            $this->setErrors('email' , trans('users::users.login_field_is_required'));
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $e)
        {
            //echo 'Password field is required.';
            $this->setErrors('password' , trans('users::users.password_field_is_required') );
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e)
        {
            //echo 'Wrong password, try again.';
            $this->setErrors('password' , trans('users::users.wrong_password') );
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
        {
            //echo 'User was not found.';
            $this->setErrors('email' , trans('users::users.user_was_not_found') );
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e)
        {
            //echo 'User is not activated.';
            $this->setErrors('email' , trans('users::users.user_is_not_activated') );
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }

        // The following is only required if the throttling is enabled
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Throttling\UserSuspendedException $e)
        {
            //echo 'User is suspended.';
            $this->setErrors('email' , trans('users::users.user_is_suspended') );
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }
        catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Throttling\UserBannedException $e)
        {
            //echo 'User is banned.';
            $this->setErrors('email' , trans('users::users.user_is_banned') );
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->getErrors());
        }

    }


}
```

My **AuthController**:

```
namespace \Users\Controllers;

use \Users\Repositories\AuthRepository;


class AuthController extends \BaseController {

    protected $auth;


    public function __construct(AuthRepository $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function login() {
        return $this->auth->login();
    }

    public function postLogin() {
        return $this->auth->postLogin();
    }

    public function logout() {
        return $this->auth->logout();
    }
}
```

My **routes**:

```
Route::get( '/login' ,                              array( 'as' => 'login' , 'uses' => 'HomeController@userLogin' ) );
Route::post('/login' ,                              array( 'as' => 'postLogin' , 'uses' => '\Users\Controllers\AuthController@postLogin' ) );
```

And finnaly the one I want to be **redirected** to:

```
Route::get('/fee/{id}/register/'  ,                 array( 'as' => 'frontend.fee.registration' ,    'uses' => 'FeeController@feeRegistration' ) );
```

Comment: Try `return redirect()->intended('profile');`. This will send them to the page they wanted to go to, or to their profile. Now assuming they were going to the event page, in the EventController, check if they already paid for the fees. If not, redirect them to the payment form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch your previous URL in Login Authentication. If successful registration, redirect to previous URL. Check If process is complete in previous URL and redirect to Payment Form. Your Request Object should have the previous URL.